# Unexpected value returned by use_count() of shared_ptr while retrieving from vector

Tags: c++11, vector, shared-ptr, reference-counting

The program below is outputting unexpected `use_count()` value when shared pointer is printed using `iterator` de-reference of `std::vector`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
#include<vector>

class A;

typedef std::shared_ptr<A>            sharedPtr;
typedef std::vector<sharedPtr>        sharedPtrVect;
typedef sharedPtrVect::const_iterator vectItr;

class A
{
  public:
    A(int inp): m_Val(inp) { /*std::cout << "*** A ctor called: " << m_Val << " ***" <<std::endl;*/ }
    ~A() { /*std::cout << "### A dtor called: " << m_Val << " ###" <<std::endl; */}

    int getVal() const { return m_Val; }

  private:
    int m_Val;
};

int main()
{
  sharedPtrVect myVect1, myVect2;
  vectItr myVectItr;
  std::shared_ptr<A> tmpPtr;

  for(int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++ ) {
    std::cout << "Pushed back: " << i << std::endl;
    tmpPtr = std::make_shared<A>(i);
    myVect1.push_back(tmpPtr);
  }

  myVectItr = myVect1.begin();

  for(  ;  myVectItr != myVect1.end() ; ++myVectItr) {
    std::cout << "-----------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Element number: " << (*myVectItr).get()->getVal() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Element use count: " << (*myVectItr).use_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-----------------------------" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Pushed back: 1
Pushed back: 2
Pushed back: 3
Pushed back: 4
Pushed back: 5
-----------------------------
Element number: 1
Element use count: 1
-----------------------------
-----------------------------
Element number: 2
Element use count: 1
-----------------------------
-----------------------------
Element number: 3
Element use count: 1
-----------------------------
-----------------------------
Element number: 4
Element use count: 1
-----------------------------
-----------------------------
Element number: 5
Element use count: 2     //I am not sure why or how this is 2?
-----------------------------
```

I don't understand how the `use_count()` for the last vector element is 2. Shouldn't it be 1 like others? I am not creating any copies of the shared pointer stored in the last element of the vector.
What am I missing here?

EDIT: I have good experience in C++98, but less experience in C++11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Shouldn't it be 1 like others? I am not creating any copies of the shared pointer stored in the last element of the vector. What am I missing here?

But you *are* creating a copy. You `push_back()` from `tmpPtr`. `push_back()` puts a copy of its argument into the vector, unless you tell it to move instead. (More on that later!)

Therefore, what happens for all but the last element is this:

- `tmpPtr` holds the only reference to the shared resource
- You `push_back()` a copy, so the copy-constructor of `shared_ptr` increments the use count to 2
- You then assign the next element to `tmpPtr`, releasing the reference to, and thereby decrementing the use count of, the previous element's resource.

But, of course, there is no subsequent assignment on the last iteration of the loop. So, at the point of printing, `tmpPtr` is still in scope, and it retains a reference to the last resource that was allocated. Hence the 1-higher refcount on the last element. This seems perfectly expected to me. ;)

To see the results you expected, you need to either destroy `tmpPtr` after you copy it but before you print, or simply avoid the copy from it in the first place. The former could be done by moving its declaration into the `for` loop, as [SirGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1277769/sirguy) pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464892/unexpected-value-returned-by-use-count-of-shared-ptr-while-retrieving-from-vec/45464989?noredirect=1#comment77891910_45464989).

However, clearly, the latter is superior. How do we do that? Well, C++11 lets us *move* instead. So, you could `emplace_back( std::move(tmpPtr) )`, in which the `move` will cast to an rvalue and thus invoke the move-constructor of the `vector` element. This will cause `tmpPtr` to release its reference upon being moved into the `vector`, effectively ensuring the use count is always 1. This leaves `tmpPtr` (like any moved-from object) in a valid-but-unspecified state, i.e. useful only to be reassigned-to.

(Note: `push_back()` will achieve the same thing, but I generally prefer using `emplace_back()` wherever possible, as it's more efficient in other situations, so it's a better default.)

Of course, you can then combine both of these: declare `tmpPtr` within the scope of the `for` loop, *and* move from it. **However**... you don't even need `tmpPtr` at all! It does not appear to serve any useful purpose. So, you could just not use it, and instead directly `emplace_back()` the result of `make_shared()`. Because the return value thereof will be an *rvalue*, it will implicitly be moved into the `vector`; no cast by `std::move` is needed.

Comment: Also, as good coding style, `tmpPtr` should be declared inside the loop, since that's the only place it is used.

Comment: @SirGuy Yup, declare at the narrowest scope possible - unless you're declaring something that doesn't need to exist at all. :P Anyway, if it _were_ needed for something, it would be simpler to declare with `auto` too, deducing from the `make_shared` expression on the RHS.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @underscore_d. Now after your explanation it seems that I should have got this one myself! But, its all in the details. That's the beauty of C++, I believe :)